# Does anyone know any C/C++ open-source client lib for OpenSocial REST?

Tags: c++, opensocial

I found one for Java and lot others in Obj-C, PHP etc but none in C/C++.

I wanted to use it on Symbian. I know we can use java to develop code on SYmbian, but I want to use C/C++ only.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I landed up using QT's http functions.